# Use jquery to put sub menus in new div

Tags: jquery

I have a menu with sub menus. I want to use jquery to move all the sub menus (unordered lists) into an expanding div. For example, I have a menu that looks like this:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li>
        <ul class="sub-menu">...</ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul class="sub-menu">...</ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul class="sub-menu">...</ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and I would like each .sub-menu to be moved into a containing div below. I currently am able to get just one .sub-menu with:

```
var put = jQuery( ".sub-menu").html();
jQuery('#nav-expand').html(put);
```

but I would like to get each one. I tried using .each() but I am either using it incorrectly or need another solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the appendTo method in jQuery to move an element

http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/

```
$( ".sub-menu" ).appendTo( "#nav-expand" );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QTwbb/

Answer (score 1):

Use `.append` instead of `.html` to move DOM elements.